# what happens to the html codes written inside the servlet program

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to know what happens to the html codes written inside the servlet?
What is the need of writing like this?

Sample code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
{   
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Using GET Method to Read Form Data";
    out.println("<html>"<head><title>"Welcome"</title></head>\n" +
                "<body><p>Welcome to servlet</p></body></html>");
}
```

Comment: Basically it generates whatever Html you write in there (if you do it right). Personally, I make .jsp pages for my Html, it gives me a better overview of things.

Comment: @VictoriaS. Is this similar to creating an html page , rather than fetching a html page that is already defined in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML code written in the servlet goes to the Client through the Container (or through web server talking with the Container) which is responsible to send a response back to the Client (browser) that, in turn, will render the HTML to the user.

Here you will find a nice explanation of what is going on behind the scenes: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading)

Answer (score 0):

An HTML page is nothing else than plain text following HTML syntax.

Hence, anything you give as a response to a HTTP request, being plain text following HTML syntax (like your String does), IS an HTML page, provided you tell the caller what is the content type of the response :

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```